# Porting C# mono from windows to mac

Tags: macos, osx-lion, mono

I wanted to know what I should and shouldn't do in code that will prevent my C# application from running on OSX Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use anything from the Microsoft.* namespaces, no PInvoke (DllImport in C#) and UI might be problematic as well.

Further information on Mono compatibility is contained in the Mono Guide Porting Winforms Applications. Existing applications can be checked for compatibility using the Migration Analyzer tool.

For more inquiries read about [Mono's App Portability](http://mono-project.com/Guidelines%3aApplication_Portability)